# Pointer arithmetic in multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

How does pointer arithmetic - specifically, addition with numbers - work if the pointer points to a multidimensional array?

When I debugged the sample program below:

```
int main(void) {
    int a[3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                 {5, 6, 7, 8},
                 {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    int *p1 = a;
    // set breakpoint ...
    ...
}
```

If I use debugger (CLion) to print `*(p1 + N)`, it gives me an array having `(N + 1)` elements, starting from element `a[N / col_size][N % col_size]`. This doesn't match my expectation. Listing actual result and expectation as below:

| Enter into debugger to print | Debugger result | Expectation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `*(p1)` | `{1}` | `{1, 2, 3, 4}` |
| `*(p1 + 2)` | `{3, 4, 5}` | `{9, 10, 11, 12}` |
| `*(p1 + 5)` | `{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}` | {an array of random numbers} |
| `*(p1 + 6)` | `{7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, -11}`. `-11` is random as it already exceeded the allocated size of the array. | {an array of random numbers} |

I understand that C stores multidimensional array in row-major order, but what confuses me is why does C provide an array of (N + 1) length for *(p1 + N)?

Comment: Your 3x4 array of ints is, in memory, exactly the same as a 12x1 array of ints... Does this help? `p1` points to the first element of the array. The executable does not "know" that you consider that block to be 3x4. The executable (and debugger) just see 12 ints in a row whose first element is being pointed at by `p1`...

Comment: Doesn't your compiler tell you that casting an `int[3][4]` to an `int *` is potentially problematic? It seems like you are expecting it to behave as `int (*p1)[4] = a;`.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yeah I understand C stores multidimensional array in row major order. However, how does C determine to return an array of (N + 1) length as the result of `*(p1 +N)`?

Comment: C certainly doesn't have a result of length `N+1` for an expression `*(p1+N)`. Your debugger is coming up with that part, and I have no idea why.

Comment: If you ask the debugger to print `*(p1-1)` or `*(p1-5)`, what output do you get? If you change `int *p1 = a;` to `int *p1 = (int *) a + 1;`, what debugger output do you get? If you change it to `int *p1 = (int *) (a+1);`, what debugger output do you get?

Comment: As @aschepler noted, what your debugger displays seems idiosyncratic of that debugger. You're looking at some data region of a binary executable. The debugger is doing its best to supply what it thinks might be relevant information. "It's a poor craftsman who blames his tools." `:)`

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good thought. `*(p1 - 1)` gives an array with 32729 elements. If I change p1 to be `int *p1 = (int *) a + 1;`, I got `{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` for `*p1`. I think it might be as what  @aschepler said it's a debugger issue.

Comment: Even before you "debug", (and I concur that the nuance of your debugger seems to be your biggest hangup), outright ignoring the warning emitted from this code, [even without heightened warning specifiers](https://godbolt.org/z/coTjoohPW), suggests maybe time should first be spent addressing that problem *first*.

Comment: Ask the debugger to show the value of `p1`, then show the output of `* (int *) X`, where `X` is that address, and `* (int *) (X + 3)` and `* (int *) Y`, where `Y` is 12 bytes plus `X`, as a single number. If this output differs from the same outputs using `p1`, it suggests the debugger is doing something with the provenance of `p1` (knowledge of how it was derived). If it shows the same output, it suggests the debugger is doing something based on the memory address alone.

Comment: Also, what is the output for printing `*&a[0][0]` and `*(&a[0][0] + 3)`? Those are entirely defined C expressions, so, if the output is the same as for the `p1` variants, it demonstrates the debugger is defective. And what is the output for `* (int *) (p1 + 11)`, `* (int *) (p1 + 12)`, `* (int *) (p1 + 13)`? Those are at and beyond the array, so I am wondering if the `N+1` number-of-items effect breaks there.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```c
int *p1 = a;
```

`a` degenerates into a pointer to its first element. It's first element is an `int[4]` so `a` degenerates into an `int (*)[4]`. gcc says as much:

> warning: initialization of 'int *' from incompatible pointer type 'int (*)[4]'

You're assigning it to an `int *`, which strict aliasing violation and therefore undefined behaviour.

If you had used the correct type, the output you would received would have been more in line with your expectations.

Comment: What does strict aliasing have to do with an implicit conversion? It is ub due to out of bounds access at `p[4]`

Comment: While the question originates in C pointer semantics, it asks largely about the debugger information, which is interesting, and this answer does not speak to that at all. Not every question involving C is just about C; this one is about the debugger.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*is answer does not speak to that at all.*", Read again?

Comment: @ikegami: Where does the answer saying anything about the debugger?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Everything up to last paragraph explains how to get the expected debugger output and therefore points out the problem that led to the unexpected output. The last paragraph explicitly states this.

Comment: @ikegami: How to get the expected output is the most trivial portion. The debugger is exhibiting interesting output not matching either treatment of `p1` as a solitary `int *`, treatment of `p1` as an `int (*)[4]`, or some behavior apparently derived from whatever knowledge of object layout in memory it has. OP explicitly noted that printing `*(p1 + N)` prints `N` values, which is quite weird. That is a major aspect of the question, and this answer completely ignores it.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, I don't care to comment about behaviour that results from UB

Comment: The question asks about the behavior of the debugger, which of course is not defined at all by the C standard. It is nonetheless a useful product to people and has its own specifications, and it appears to be misbehaving in this case. The question specifically asks about that, so any answer that does not address it is deficient. If a question were tagged C and asked about using Unix system calls from C and an answer failed to include the requested information about the Unix system calls because they are undefined by the C answer, it would be a deficient answer. This answer is the same.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, I didn't say the behaviour isn't specified. I said they fed it garbage, and they got garbage out. That is NOT interesting, and that is not relevant. If they (or you) still get weird results without putting garbage in, they can ask a question about that.

Comment: @ikegami: They did not feed the debugger garbage. Debuggers are, by definition, supposed to help you find bugs in programs. To do that, they **must** work with “bad” data. The program might be bad in the view of the C standard, but it is entirely valid for what the debugger is supposed to work with. Further, as we see from the displayed output of the debugger for `*(p1)`, `p1` has been set to point to the first `int` in the array. It is entirely valid for an `int *` to be pointing to an `int` in an array of an array of `int`…

Comment: … So, when asked to print `*(p1+2)`, the debugger ought to print the `int` at the location two `int` beyond where `p1` points. It should not be printing 3 `int` for `*(p1+2)`, 6 `int` for `*(p1+5)`, and so on. The question asks about that. This answer does not answer the question that was asked, so it is a bad answer.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Of course not, but `p1` contains garbage. So whatever it prints is wrong. Re "*This answer does not answer the question that was asked*", You are mistaken. You don't like my answer, but that doesn't mean it wasn't answered.

Comment: @ikegami: `p1` does not contain garbage. The C standard does not define what it contains, but the C standard is not the only applicable information. The debugger is supposed to provide debugging services, and it failed. The questions asks about the behavior of this debugger, this answer does not answer that question, so this is a bad answer.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*`p1` does not contain garbage.*" Yes it does. It can contain anything on any given run. Again, I don't comment on the specific behaviour of code with Undefined Behaviour, and your spam isn't going to change that.

Comment: @ikegami: No, `p1` cannot contain anything on any given run. The C standard does not specify what it contains, but that does not mean it actually can contain anything on any given run. It only means that would be permitted by the C standard. But, once again, the C standard is not the only applicable information. Further, the C standard does not constrain the debugger. You are trying to apply a specification, the C standard, to software that is not made to conform to the C standard. It is like complaining a FORTRAN program has behavior not defined by the C standard. Of course it does…

Comment: … A FORTRAN compiler’s purpose is to compile FORTRAN, not to comply with the C standard. And a debugger’s purpose is to help debug programs, not to comply with the C standard. What the C standard says about anything is essentially irrelevant to this question about how the debugger is behaving. As a practical matter, the compiler generated code that put the address of the first `int` in `A` into `p1`. The debugger ought to be working with that, and it should not be exhibiting the odd behavior shown in the question. The question asks about that, and this answer does not answer it, so it is bad.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*What the C standard says about anything is essentially irrelevant to this question about how the debugger is behaving.*", The debugger's job is to print the value. But the value is junk, so you get junk. You're assuming the debugger's output is not based on the value, and that's pure conjecture. Again, if the behaviour is incorrect for a valid value, then feel free to ask a question about.  Again, I don't comment on the specific behaviour of code with Undefined Behaviour, and your spam isn't going to change that.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Prove my last sentence wrong if it is. Until you do, you're just spamming. Please stop.

Comment: @ikegami: What last sentence? I suppose I believe you are not going to answer the question that the OP asked. But labeling something “spam“ is just name-calling, not reasoning. Getting back to reasoning, an indeterminate value or whatever you mean by “garbage” or “junk” is not an actual thing. It is an abstraction the C standard uses to allow flexibility in implementations. In the actual process, each byte of memory, including registers, has a specific value. A function of a debugger is to examine, display, and manipulate process state in ways useful for debugging…

Comment: … The debugger ought to be working with the process state, **whatever it is**. But it is doing something odd, it is showing a number of numbers that varies in an odd way depending on the address. There is some distinct cause for that, and it is not answered by incanting “garbage.” The question asks about that behavior, and this answer does not answer the question that was asked, so this answer is bad.